# Upload button not being shown Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading

For some reason when I try to make the upload button for the admin to use, the upload button is not showing up, can someone take a look and tell me what is wrong with it?

test.blade.php

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $object->Name }}<br><br>
    <b>Email: </b>{{$object->Email}}<br><br>
      @foreach ($data3 as $currentUser)
        <a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['user'=>$currentUser->id])  !!}">
            <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class ="fa fa-plus"></i>Upload Images</button>
     </a> 
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

HomeController (where I get the id for one to one relationship purpose)

```
public function getInfo($id) {
  $data = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();
      $data3=UserImage::where('user_id',$id)->get();
 return view('test',compact('data','data3'));
```

Comment: If I were to put the button function out of the for loop, it will appear but doesn't redirect me to another page when I click it

Comment: Is your <a> tag closed with an </a> after the </button> ?

Comment: @Serge tks for replying, I have tried putting the </a> but it didn't work, still not being shown, in the past I also didn't put </a> and it still appear

Comment: What does it render to when you look at it in the debug view?

Comment: How do I do a debug view? Sorry it my first time hearing it

Comment: You on a mac? Option+Command+i in Chrome...

Comment: I'm using windows, or just right click view page source?

Comment: Control+Shift+i then... Take a look at the doc

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: It seem like there is no sign of the upload code being shown

Comment: Are you looking at the correct view file?  /resources/view/test.blade.php or are you looking at View.blade.php?

Comment: I am looking at test.blade.php, sorry the view.blade.php is to make it more easier to see @Silveanus Matiku will edit the question now

Comment: are you sure the `id` has `userimage` records in the database?

Comment: There is no records in the userImage table yet because right now I just want to make sure that when I upload a file, the user_id must be equal to the id of the person name when the admin see their information. But right now I couldn't even access to the upload page because the button is missing @norrisOduro Or am I doing it wrongly? If yes could you instruct me on what to do?

Comment: In your controller, you are checking for records in the `userimage` table matching the `id` you pass to the function. for it to work insert data into the table and try again. You need data in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you are getting all `UserImages` and sending it to your view.

```
public function getInfo($id) {
  $data = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();
      $data3=UserImage::where('user_id',$id)->get();
 return view('test',compact('data','data3'));
}
```

Then you are iterating over the collection to display an upload button for all the results you get.

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $object->Name }}<br><br>
    <b>Email: </b>{{$object->Email}}<br><br>
      @foreach ($data3 as $currentUser)
        <a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['user'=>$currentUser->id])  !!}">
            <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class ="fa fa-plus"></i>Upload Images</button>
     </a> 
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But the problem is, if the `$data3` which is the `UserImages` is empty, then the `foreach` is ignored since its empty and that does not display your button.

To display the button, make sure you have data in your database so that the `$data3` is not empty.